# Need to optimize the query by avoiding the union. Please Help the other option the query is as below

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT  image_name
    ,   document_id
    ,   document_name
    ,   document_category
    ,   workflow_state_name
    ,   container_name
    ,   modelyear
    ,   build_phase
    ,   revision_level
    ,   owner
    ,   container_id
    ,   document_description description
FROM container_document_view
WHERE document_id IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'icon_folder.gif' image_name
            ,   container_id document_id
            ,   container_name document_name
            ,   '' document_category
            ,   workflow_state_name
            ,   container_name
            ,   modelyear
            ,   build_phase
            ,   revision_level
            ,   owner
            ,   container_id
            ,   container_description description
FROM container_details_view
WHERE container_id NOT IN (
        SELECT container_id
        FROM document
    )
UNION
SELECT  image_name
    ,   document_id
    ,   document_name
    ,   document_category
    ,   workflow_state_name
    ,   container_name
    ,   modelyear
    ,   build_phase
    ,   revision_level
    ,   owner
    ,   container_id
    ,   document_description description
FROM container_link_view
WHERE container_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY container_name, container_id, document_name, modelyear, build_phase, revision_level
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to avoid it ?

If it's too slow you might check if it's possible to change to `UNION ALL` instead, which avoids the costly `DISTINCT`.

Additionally the `NOT IN` might be more efficient when you rewrite it as a `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: why i am asking to replace the union is to optimize it and the existing query take more temporary memory space in database, so need the other solution.

Comment: From the names after FROM, it looks like you are querying views. Maybe you should have a look at the underlying tables for possible optimization.

Comment: I am unable send the view. but it is straight forward.. no need to optimize in that..

Comment: Then try the UNION ALL first.

Comment: Without additonal information (DDL, row counts, view definition) it's impossible to suggest any other optimization.

Comment: Few details i have give to you Number of executions               = 1
 Number of compilations             = 1
 Worst preparation time (ms)        = 70
 Best preparation time (ms)         = 70
 Internal rows deleted              = 0
 Internal rows inserted             = 0
 Rows read                          = 1800076
 Internal rows updated              = 0
 Rows written                       = 34913
 Statement sorts                    = 137
 Statement sort overflows           = 14